# Help for installation

Tags: 14.04

I downloaded Ubuntu 14.04.2 32bit and my laptop doesn't have a OS on it. Well, when I try to install, it says I don't have enough free disk space. I tried running `sudo gparted` in the terminal, but it says `can't run outside partition`.

What do I do?